# CPU stress with PowerShell remoting

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I need to generate some load on about 100 Windows 2012 R2 servers. The idea I have is to use PowerShell remoting to kick off my script the generate the CPU load. I am also trying to control the load by checking the current load and if it is over X% don't spawn a new job. It's not the most elegant script, but the script works if I execute it locally. When I run it remotely things go wrong.

1. it seems as if the foreach loop does nothing. So I just have an idle process
2. it will start about 15 jobs with no issues then the rest all report as having failed.

I have tried various methods of calling the function. I have modified the function so that it contains a server variable but still not getting the desired result. I have replaced `Start-Job` with `Invoke-Command`. PSRemoting is working I can do basic tasks on the remote servers.

Any guidance would be appreciated

Below is my code

```
function Invoke-CPUStress
{
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    $duration
)

$start = (get-date).AddMinutes(1)
$end = $start.AddMinutes($duration)

while ((Get-Date) -lt $start)
{
    sleep -Seconds 10   
}

while ((get-date) -lt $end)
{
    $Load = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average).Average
    If ($Load -lt 60)
    {
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
            $result = 1;
            foreach ($number in 1..2147483647)
            {
                $result = $result * $number
                sleep -Milliseconds 1
            }
        }   
    }
}

Get-Job | Stop-Job
Get-Job | Remove-Job
}

Invoke-CPUStress -duration 5
```